# gcc11: ambiguous overload for ‘operator&&’

Tags: c++

GCC 11.1.0, сборка программы заканчивается ошибкой:

```
#include <variant>
#include <map>

bool operator && (const std::variant<bool, double> &, const std::variant<bool, double> &);

int main()
{
    std::map<int, bool> vals;
    vals.find(1);

    return 0;   // ok
}
```

Ошибка:

```
/usr/include/c++/11/type_traits:2942:7: error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator&&’ (operand types are ‘std::true_type’ {aka ‘std::integral_constant<bool, true>’} and ‘std::true_type’ {aka ‘std::integral_constant<bool, true>’})
```

При этом ошибки нет в GCC 8.4.0, GCC 10.3.0, Clang-11, Clang-12.

В чем тут проблема и как ее исправить?

Comment: [Перепостил](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67693089/2752075) на английский SO, посмотрим что будет.

Comment: Скорее всего, баг в последней версии.

Comment: На английском SO подсказали [баг gcc #51577](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51577). На вид это оно и есть, вот только баг старый, а сломалось почему-то только сейчас.

Answer (score 0):

В текущем trunk GCC ошибка сборки пропала.